# Derivative of the inverse of a certain variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to take a derivative of the inverse of a certain variable, e.g., being the function:

```
f[x_, a_, T_] := (a x^3)/T
```

I want the derivative with respect to $1/T$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)}=ax^3$$

It doesn't work with:

```
D[f[x, a, T], 1/T]
```

> [image]
>
> $\frac{\partial f(x,a,T)}{\partial \frac{1}{T}}$

neither if I define:

```
b=1/T
```

And then ask for:

```
D[f[x, a, b], b]
```

It always state "1/T is not a valid variable"

> [image]
>
> $\frac{\partial f(x,a,T)}{\partial \frac{1}{T}}$

Comment: `Block[{c}, D[f[x, a, 1/c], c] /. c -> 1/T]`. The `Block` is only there in case you happen to have `c` defined somewhere else.

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple. Appreciate!!!

Comment: @march Why do not you put this as an answer? That was interesting for me. I needed this information the other day and I had not found it.

Comment: @march Seems simple to you, but to other users it's cool

Comment: @LCarvalho. I mean, I would guess that this is a duplicate, but I only had time to do a little searching, so I haven't found one yet. Nonetheless, I'll quickly write something up.

Answer (score 11):

you can also use the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)}=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial \frac{1}{T}}{\partial T}}$$

```
 D[f[x, a, T], T]/D[1/T, T]
```

> a x^3

Answer (score 9):

You had the right idea, except for `Set`ting the value of `b` to be `1/T`. The reason that doesn't work is that `D` does not have the `Attribute` `HoldAll` (or variants) which means that its arguments get evaluated before `D` does. That is, if you do

```
b = 1/T;
D[f[x, a, 1/b], b]
```

you get the error because `1/T` has been put in place of `b` *before* the derivative is taken. The fix is to wrap the entire expression in the `Block` scoping construct, which will delay the evaluation of `b` until after the derivative is taken, like so:

```
f[x_, a_, T_] := (a*x^3)/T
b = 1/T;
Block[{b}, D[f[x, a, 1/b], b]]
(* a x^3 *)
```

Alternatively, use an undefined symbol and use a replacement rule. I prefer this version because I like to avoid cluttering up the global namespace with defined symbols. So:

```
f[x_, a_, T_] := (a*x^3)/T
Block[{c}, D[f[x, a, 1/c], c] /. c -> 1/T]
(* a x^3 *)
```

Comment: Now yes. Very good tip.